# Get postback value of custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I have a code:

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  writer.AddAttribute("data-value", "{ \"test\": 3 }");
  base.Render(writer);
}
```

I am using a new class called DataField, which inherits HiddenField. The whole goal of this is be able to send a JSON object, modify it from the client, and post it back to the server. So, using jQuery:

```
var data = $('#DataField').data('value');
data.test = 1;
$('#DataField').attr('data-value',JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now, from here, how could I get the `data-value` attribute postedback from there server? I know that the whole page is posted back, so, it should be somewhere, no?
overriding `LoadPostData` does not help as the attribute contained in there is `value` and nothing else.

Comment: So you're saving JSON inside a data attribute? :/ Have you considered having a data attribute for each of the fields on your JSON object instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that the whole page is posted back, so, it should be somewhere, no?

Nope.  The "whole page" is not posted to the server.  Form values are posted to the server.  In order for the server-side code (the instance of the `DataField` basically) to receive a value then it needs to be set as the *value* of that `input type="hidden"`.  `data-*` attributes are used client-side, they're not posted to the server as part of a form.

So when you do this:

```
$('#DataField').attr('data-value',JSON.stringify(data));
```

You'll also want to do this:

```
$('#DataField').val(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This will set the JSON-encoded string of `data` as the value of the `input type="hidden"`, which will be posted back to the server and available here:

```
SomeDataField.Value
```

Comment: Ahh, that's cool! I ended up using your idea. Save the data sent by the server in the `data-value`, and when the data is modified, send it back to the server through the `value` attribute. Thanks a lot! :D